# Is there a way to use my color scheme to fill a barplot using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am graphing barplots using ggplot2.

So far all my graphs are coming up the way I expect them to. However, I have a graph or set of graphs that do not.
I have tried going through all the stackoverflow questions regarding color scheme adding to a barplot but none seem to work.

I have tried using the previous code that I made and just changing the variable that I am looking at. For some reason this doesn't work even though there are the exact same groupings.

```
    ggplot(data = df, aes(status, fill = status)) +
      geom_bar() +
      labs(title = "Current Status", x = "status", y = "Count") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = c("None", "current", "extra"))+
      scale_fill_mine(palette = "main", guide = "none")
```

But I get a graph that is just greyscale. (I also have trouble adding my graph here to show you what I am seeing)

I expect to have a frequency bar graph that has 3 bars with three different colors.

Comment: Where does `scale_fill_mine` come from? did you want `scale_fill_manual`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not sure where `scale_fill_mine()` is coming from. See if this example proides a method you can use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    status = LETTERS[1:3],
    n = c(5,15,10)
  ) %>% 
  uncount(n)


main_colors <- c("grey70", "turquoise3", "coral2")


ggplot(data = df, aes(status, fill = status)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = main_colors, guide = "none") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("None", "current", "extra")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(
    title = "Current Status", 
    x = "status", 
    y = "Count"
  )
```

[image]